# GDB: How to convert enum value to string in GDB script

Tags: arrays, enums, gdb

I have the following enum in my code:

```
enum myenum {
  ready,
  waiting,
  stopping,
};
```

then I have a struct like so:

```
typedef struct {
  int a;
  int b;
  uint8 step;  // this is set using myenum.
} mystruct;
```

During GDB debugging session I am trying to declare an array of strings and then use its index to convert to string but running into couple of issues:

1. It requires me to keep the array elements to be of the same size:

```
(gdb) set $step_str={"ready", "waiting", "stopping"}
array elements must all be the same size
```

2. If I fix #1 by adding spaces and make all strings of same size then printf doesn't work with it:

```
(gdb) set $step_str={"ready   ", "waiting ", "stopping"}
(gdb) printf "step=%s", $step_str[0]
Attempt to take address of value not located in memory.
```

3. The only way I could make it work is by using output command but the problem with output also is that if I end up adding a lot of spaces to a particular string then it is printed like this:

```
(gdb) set $step_str={"ready                     ", "this_is_a_long_enum_symbol"}
(gdb) output $step_str[0]
"ready", ' ' <repeats 21 times>
```

Having "' ' <repeats 21 times>" doesn't look nice and a bit confusing to the new readers of my output. I am trying to do this with a lot of enums and trying to gather debug info using GDB scripts on a core dump.

Another solution I thought of was to declare a helper command and make it set a variable but that becomes really long if I have several enums. For example:

```
define enum2str
  if $arg0 == 0
    set $retval="ready"
  end
  if $arg0 == 1
    set $retval="this_is_a_long_enum_symbol"
  end
  ... and so on but this will grow crazy if I have 20 enum values ...
```

Is there a better way to convert enum value to string? So I don't have to add those spaces to make array of same size elements and don't get that  in my output?

Thanks much in advance!

Comment: Does it have to be a string? Why don't you just cast it to the enum, like `output (enum myenum)1`?

Comment: You are the best. So simple it was. Thanks, casting it like that works great.

Comment: What I didn't see in your question is a reason why you don't declare `step` as `enum myenum step`.  If you did this, then in GDB `print obj.step` will print the corresponding enum value as a string.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the [`$_as_string`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Funs.html#index-_0024_005fas_005fstring_002c-convenience-function) convenience function is what you're after.

```
$_as_string(value)

    Return the string representation of value.

    This function is useful to obtain the textual label (enumerator) of an
    enumeration value. For example, assuming the variable node is of an
    enumerated type:

    (gdb) printf "Visiting node of type %s\n", $_as_string(node)
    Visiting node of type NODE_INTEGER
```